# Firestore "Reference" versus "DocumentReference"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

So there's a Firestore [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference) object created with `db.ref("parent/child")`.

And there's a Firestore [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) object created with `doc(db, "parent", "child")`

The documentation makes it seems like these are slightly different. But how are they different? Why would I use one versus the other?

Comment: Those are from 2 different databases. You use `Reference` if you're working with `Realtime Database` and `DocumentReference` if you're working with `Firestore Database`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the shared references points to a particular location in a database. However, even if both, the Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore, are Firebase products, both are two totally different products, with totally different concepts.

The first reference points to a node that exists in the Realtime Database, while the second one, points to a document that exists in a Firestore collection.